# Enumerate environments within theorems

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems, enumerate

How to create an environment for enumerating that allows one to identify the enumeration with the theorem environment?

Example:

---

**Definition 1.1**  Let X be a set. An algebra over X is a collection C of subsets of X satisfying

**D 1.1.1** If A is an element of C, then X\A is an element of C;

**D 1.1.2** If A and B are both elements of C, then the union A U B is an element of C.

---

**Proposition 1.1** Let C be an algebra over a set X; then the following senteces are true

**P 1.1.1** The empty set is an element of C;

**P 1.1.2** The set X is an element of C;

**P 1.1.3** Every finite union of elements of C is an element of C;

**P 1.1.4** Every finite intersection of elements of C is an element of C.

---

It would be quite useful if I could labeled then, to a further reference.

Comment: It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

This will also serve as a test case and ensure that the solution actually works for you.

Comment: Peter Grill's comment is particularly relevant here because there are *so many* different ways to create theorems- which one are you using?

Comment: @cmhughes: in this particular case, I disagree. The solution I provided will work with only some minor formatting changes whenever the theorem-like structures are defined as environments and have an associated counter (and those conditions are always satisfied with the usual methods for creating theorems: `amsthm`, `ntheorem`, `mdframed`).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I agree- your solution is very robust. However, if a specific theorem package was specified then there would be no need for the `etoolbox` as the `setlist` trick you wrote could have been built into the environment definition

Comment: @cmhughes: Ah, I see your point. Should we delete our comments or do you think we can leave them?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina personally, I think these comments are good because they show alternatives. I like your `ntheorem` solution too- you should be able to get rid of the `etoolbox` though, and use `\theoremprework{<setlist stuff in here>}`

Comment: @cmhughes: you're right. I will incorporate your suggestion into my answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's one possible solution using the [enumitem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package to define a new list-like environment whose label uses a variable prefix; this prefix is controlled by a macro and, with the help of the `etoolbox` package, the theorem-like environments are patched  to redefine the prefix. Labeling and cross-referencig items is then done as usual.

According to **barbara beeton**'s comment, provisions were made to have the labels with a final period and the cross-references without it. Also, italicized item numbers were suppressed.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[chapter]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}[chapter]

\newcommand\EnumPrefix{}

\newlist{senenum}{enumerate}{10}
\setlist[senenum]{label=\EnumPrefix.,ref=\EnumPrefix,leftmargin=*}

\AtBeginEnvironment{defi}{\renewcommand\EnumPrefix{\normalfont\bfseries D.\thedefi.\arabic*}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{prop}{\renewcommand\EnumPrefix{\normalfont\bfseries P.\theprop.\arabic*}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}

\begin{defi}
Let $X$ be a set. An algebra over $X$ is a collection $C$ of subsets of $X$ satisfying
\begin{senenum}
\item If $A$ is an element of $C$, then $X\setminus A$ is an element of $C$;
\item  If $A$ and $B$ are both elements of $C$, then the union $A\cup B$ is an element of $C$.
\end{senenum}
\end{defi}

\begin{prop}
Let $C$ be an algebra over a set $X$; then the following senteces are true
\begin{senenum}
\item\label{ite:algempty} The empty set is an element of $C$;
\item The set $X$ is an element of $C$;
\item  Every finite union of elements of $C$ is an element of $C$;
\item\label{ite:alginter} Every finite intersection of elements of $C$ is an element of $C$.
\end{senenum}
\end{prop}

In the proof of the equivalence of \ref{ite:alginter} and \ref{ite:algempty}, we used,...

\end{document}
```

[image]

The above approach focuses on the list-like environment, therefore it is ready to use (with only minor changes) in the case in which `ntheorem` is used to define the theorem-like structures (`ntheorem` doesn't use a default period at the end of theorem numbering):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[chapter]
\theoremstyle{changebreak}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}[chapter]

\newcommand\EnumPrefix{}

\newlist{senenum}{enumerate}{10}
\setlist[senenum]{label=\EnumPrefix,leftmargin=*}

\AtBeginEnvironment{defi}{\renewcommand\EnumPrefix{\normalfont\bfseries D.\thedefi.\arabic*}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{prop}{\renewcommand\EnumPrefix{\normalfont\bfseries P.\theprop.\arabic*}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}

\begin{defi}
Let $X$ be a set. An algebra over $X$ is a collection $C$ of subsets of $X$ satisfying
\begin{senenum}
\item If $A$ is an element of $C$, then $X\setminus A$ is an element of $C$;
\item  If $A$ and $B$ are both elements of $C$, then the union $A\cup B$ is an element of $C$.
\end{senenum}
\end{defi}

\begin{prop}
Let $C$ be an algebra over a set $X$; then the following senteces are true
\begin{senenum}
\item\label{ite:algempty} The empty set is an element of $C$;
\item The set $X$ is an element of $C$;
\item  Every finite union of elements of $C$ is an element of $C$;
\item\label{ite:alginter} Every finite intersection of elements of $C$ is an element of $C$.
\end{senenum}
\end{prop}

In the proof of the equivalence of \ref{ite:alginter} and \ref{ite:algempty}, we used,...

\end{document}
```

[image]

When using `ntheorem`, there's even another option, not requiring the `etoolbox` package since `\theoremprework` can be used to redefine appropriately the prefix used for the list-like environment (as suggested by **cmhughes** in a comment to the original question); here's the code corresponding to this approach and producing the same result as before:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand\EnumPrefix{}

\theoremprework{\renewcommand\EnumPrefix{\normalfont\bfseries P.\theprop.\arabic*}}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[chapter]
\theoremstyle{changebreak}
\theoremprework{\renewcommand\EnumPrefix{\normalfont\bfseries D.\thedefi.\arabic*}}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}[chapter]

\newlist{senenum}{enumerate}{10}
\setlist[senenum]{label=\EnumPrefix,leftmargin=*}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}

\begin{defi}
Let $X$ be a set. An algebra over $X$ is a collection $C$ of subsets of $X$ satisfying
\begin{senenum}
\item If $A$ is an element of $C$, then $X\setminus A$ is an element of $C$;
\item  If $A$ and $B$ are both elements of $C$, then the union $A\cup B$ is an element of $C$.
\end{senenum}
\end{defi}

\begin{prop}
Let $C$ be an algebra over a set $X$; then the following senteces are true
\begin{senenum}
\item\label{ite:algempty} The empty set is an element of $C$;
\item The set $X$ is an element of $C$;
\item  Every finite union of elements of $C$ is an element of $C$;
\item\label{ite:alginter} Every finite intersection of elements of $C$ is an element of $C$.
\end{senenum}
\end{prop}

In the proof of the equivalence of \ref{ite:alginter} and \ref{ite:algempty}, we used,...

\end{document}
```

Comment: keeping the period at the end of the xrefs is confusing.  also (depending on house style), italicizing item numbers may be deprecated.  methods of avoiding those situations would be appreciated.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: thank you for your comment; I've updated my answer incorporating your suggestions.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina how can I indent the list, in the first solution? Thanks.

Comment: @PauloHenrique it depends on the desired kind of indentation. You can change `leftmargin=*` for `leftmargin=<length>`, where `<length>` is an appropriate length.

Comment: If I add a length in `leftmargin` it goes to the left instead to the right (inside the text). I tried `rightmargin`, but the same problem occurred.

Comment: @PauloHenrique What value did you use for `leftmargin`? Since the labels are wide, you need a rather big value.

Comment: I set 5 pt on `leftmargin`

Comment: @PauloHenrique as I said, since your labels are wide, you need a bigger value.